# retreival of x-axis value on a google chart getselection

Tags: charts, google-visualization, selection

I use a column chart. When clicking at one of the rows in the diagram my listener trigger an event:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', renderList);
```

I am only able to retrieve the number 2456 and not 6. Number 6 is the value of my first column. I have two columns in my table. Can someone please help me with this? I've been struggling for quite some time.

This is the instantiation of the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("select").change(function () {
        drawChart();
     });

        function drawChart() {
            var inputData = {
                rooms: $("#Rooms").val(), area: $("#Areas").val(), apartmentType: $("#ApartmentType").val(),
                queue: $("#Queue").val(), year: $("#Years").val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AllocatedApartments", "Statistics")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: inputData,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    tdata.addColumn('number', 'Antal bostäder');
                    tdata.addColumn('number', 'Kötid');
                    $.each(data.GroupedList, function (key, value) {
                        tdata.addRow([value.QueueTime, value.Count])
                    });

                    var options = {
                        title: 'Förmedlade bostäder',
                        backgroundColor: "F1F1F1",
                        colors: ['73a948'],
                        legend: { "position": "none" },
                        vAxis: { title: 'Antal förmedlade bostäder', titleTextStyle: { color: 'gray' } },
                        hAxis: { title: 'Kötidsintervall (antal år)', titleTextStyle: { color: 'gray' } }
                    };

                    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(tdata, options);
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', renderList);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

In the function renderList I want to fetch the label of the row selected:

```
function renderList() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var value = tdata.getValue(selection.row, selection.column );
    alert(value)

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("RenderApartmentList", "Statistics")',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: inputData,
    success: function (data) {
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data)
        $("#myPartialViewContainer").html(html);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Ett fel uppstod, var god försök igen om en liten stund.")
    }
});
```

}

Comment: It'd help to show relevant code.

Comment: @AntoJurković I'm trying to fetch the selected row's label, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: It's hard to help without your code, we will be just guessing about it. Just paste the code into your question or make some example at jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, now you have the code.

Comment: If you need to access a different column, specify the column you want to use instead of getting it from the selection: `var value = tdata.getValue(selection[0].row, 0 );`.

Answer (score 0):

For this part of code

```
function renderList() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var value = tdata.getValue(selection.row, selection.column );
    alert(value)
    ...
```

you have to receive error in console log:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid row index undefined. Should be in the range [0-53].
```

`getSelection()` returns an array. So you have to change that to:

```
    function renderList() {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var value = tdata.getValue(selection[0].row, selection[0].column );
```

See google docs [about Column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart): *getSelection() Array of selection elements*

And [Extended description of getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visgetselection)

Comment: Also, test for the length of `selection`, since `#getSelection` will return an empty array when the user deselects an element.